# Syntax error in a compound sql statement around Start Transaction, i guess

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with this compound mysql. I am using the Start Transaction for the first time. So anything will be really helpful.

```
START TRANSACTION
INSERT
INTO
  p_ucourse(
  course_name,
  course_goal,
  course_time,
  course_creator_id,
  course_status
)
VALUES(
 'This Course',
 'Goal of this course',
 480,
 1,
 1
);
SET
ucourse_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT
INTO
  r_ucourse_module(course_id,
  module_id,
  rank)
VALUES(ucourse_id, 1, 1);

INSERT
INTO
  r_ucourse_eu(
  course_id,
  lu_id,
  rank,
  afterclass
  )
VALUES(ucourse_id, 1, 1, 0);
COMMIT
```

And it throws up the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT
INTO
  p_ucourse(
    course_name,
    course_goal,
    course_time,' at line 2
```

I am not being able to get the syntax of the thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing semi-colon at the end of the first line. Ditto with `Commit` Try:

```
START TRANSACTION;
..
..
COMMIT;
```

See [START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, and ROLLBACK Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) for a few examples.

...
...

as for your other issue, consider the below:

```
create table MyThings
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing varchar(100) not null
);
insert MyThings(thing) values ('Fred, the pet Anchovy');
SET ucourse_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); -- Error 1193: unknown sys var ... 
SET @ucourse_id = LAST_INSERT_ID(); -- YIPPIE, not a problem (user variable)
```

So, the first one above (`SET ucourse_id`) choked, because it was assumed to be a LOCAL Variable (as it did not have an `@` sign). The whole thing was not running in a stored proc/function (I assumed). Local Variables need to have life breathed into them with a `DECLARE`.

but...

```
declare k int; -- error, can't do this outside of a store proc/func etc
```

So, one should read up on User Variables vs Local Variables, when and how one can use them.

**Local Variables:** `DECLARE` can be used in Stored Procedures, Functions, Events, and Triggers. But they need to occur grouped together at the top only, before any commands and typcially right after `BEGIN`. Otherwise, other errors will occur.

**User Variables:** (such as @myBirthday) No `DECLARE` is used with them. They are used free-wheeling with less restrictions, such as when you are just hacking around outside of Stored procs, functions, events, and triggers (but can certainly be used inside of them). Note, these are the only type of variables that will succeed with [`PREPARE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html), such as the `PREPARE stmt001 FROM @theSql;` part of it. This last fact is not typically figured out until one wastes a lot of time with it.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Really appreciate. Will accept the answer in 8 mins. Also, that lead to another error at SET
 #1193 - Unknown system variable 'ucourse_id'. ANy help there?

Comment: Thanks @Drew. Will read up more. U really helped in a stiff deadline situation. Really appreciate.